# OneSignal Ionic Callback function not being called on notification open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

I am using Ionic Framework. 
I have successfully registered and able to receive the notifications. 
But my callback function is not being called when I open a notification. 
It just gets called on the first init(). 
I have placed the code in the app.js run function() after device is ready. 
I searched a few forums but I could not find any solution.
Below is the code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() { 
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar    above the keyboard 
// for form inputs) 
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) { 
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true); 
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true); 
} 
var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) { 
console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData)); 
if (jsonData.additionalData && jsonData.additionalData.targetUrl) { 
var state = $injector.get($state); 
$state.go(jsonData.additionalData.targetUrl); 
} 
}; 
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("MY-API_KEY", { 
googleProjectNumber: "MY-GOOGLE-PROJECT-NUMBER", 
autoRegister: true 
}, 
notificationOpenedCallback({title: 'test'})); 
window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(true); 
window.plugins.OneSignal.enableNotificationsWhenActive(true); 
// oneSignal.init(); 
if (window.StatusBar) { 
// org.apache.cordova.statusbar required 
StatusBar.styleDefault(); 
} 
});
```

The callback function is fired only when the app starts the first time and init is called.
When I open a received notification the callback function is not fired.
I am doing this just for android. Can anybody please help me out?

Below are the ionic info:
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0 
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0 
Gulp local: 
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4 
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.15 
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.2 
OS: 
Node Version: v4.4.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following code:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("50d4a379-9e94-44cf-bba8-06b6bbc312da", { 
  googleProjectNumber: "724048084872", 
  autoRegister: true 
}, 
notificationOpenedCallback({title: 'test'}));
```

TO:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("50d4a379-9e94-44cf-bba8-06b6bbc312da", { 
  googleProjectNumber: "724048084872", 
  autoRegister: true 
}, 
notificationOpenedCallback);
```